# Download shapefile with electric substation data at state or county level for the United States

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, government

I would like to know about where I could find electric substation data for states in the US, that can be downloaded as a point shapefile or file geodatabase feature class. I am particularly interested to find substation data for the states of California, Nevada and Arizona. I am searching for data that would show information about the substation status, max-min voltage, NAICS code and possibly number transmission lines passing through these substations. I was able to find multiple resources for California 'https://data.ca.gov/dataset/california-electric-substations' and 'https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/california-electric-substations-64b59/resource/21777503-daec-4b66-b52e-3b582d066f8e?inner_span=True'. However was not able to find any data for Nevada or Arizona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Homeland Infrastructure Foundation-Level Data: Electric Substations](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/electric-substations/data)

> This feature class/shapefile represents electric power substations
>   primarily associated with electric power transmission. In this layer,
>   substations are considered facilities and equipment that switch,
>   transform, or regulate electric power at voltages equal to, or greater
>   than, 69 kilovolts. Substations with a maximum operating voltage less
>   than 69 kilovolts may be included, depending on the availability of
>   authoritative sources, but coverage of these features should not be
>   considered complete. The Substations feature class/shapefile includes
>   taps, a location where power on a transmission line is tapped by
>   another transmission line. The following updates have been made since
>   the previous release: 7,144 features added, geographic coverage
>   expanded to include Guam, Northern Mariana Islands, and Virgin
>   Islands.